# Use DocuSign.Integration.Client.dll v1.4, got ACCOUNT NOT AUTHORIZED FOR ENVELOPE with GetRecipientView

Tags: docusignapi

The login was using a developer sandbox account. If the recipent email is the same as the sender login acoount email, everything worked fine. But if they are different, the rest error `ACCOUNT NOT AUTHORIZED FOR ENVELOPE` was thrown when calling envelope.GetRecipientView. The envelop was created successfully. The see my code below.

```
Private Sub SendDocToSign(ByVal docPDF As Byte())

Dim clsQuote As New clsQuote

Dim objDatabase As New clsDatabase

Try

' configure application's integrator key and webservice url

 RestSettings.Instance.IntegratorKey = AppSettings("IntegratorsKey")

 RestSettings.Instance.DocuSignAddress = "https://" & AppSettings("PAGE_DOCUSIGN")

 RestSettings.Instance.WebServiceUrl = RestSettings.Instance.DocuSignAddress & "/restapi/v2"

 RestSettings.Instance.FeatureSetId = "........"

 System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls Or System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3

 System.Net.ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = False

' credentials for sending account

Dim account As Account = New Account()

 account.Email = AppSettings("APIUserEmail")

 account.Password = AppSettings("Password")

 account.ApiPassword = AppSettings("Password")

 account.Proxy = New System.Net.WebProxy("Proxy Server", True)

account.Proxy.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials



' make the Login API call

Dim result As Boolean = account.Login()

If result = False Then

 Response.Write("Login Failed: " & result & " " & account.RestError.message)

Return

End If

Dim recipients As Recipients = New Recipients()

Dim signer As Signer = New Signer

 signer.email = MyBase.pEmail

 signer.name = MyBase.pContactName

 signer.recipientId = "1"

 signer.routingOrder = "1"

'signer.clientUserId = "1000"

Dim Signers(0) As Signer

Signers(0) = signer

recipients.signers = Signers

Dim tabs As New TabCollection()

Dim tab As New Tab()

tab.pageNumber = 3

tab.xPosition = 31

tab.yPosition = 382

 tab.recipientId = "1"

tab.documentId = 1

tabs.signHereTabs.Add(tab)



Dim texttab As New TextTab()

texttab.pageNumber = 3

texttab.xPosition = 31

texttab.yPosition = 475

 texttab.recipientId = "1"

texttab.documentId = 1

tabs.textTabs.Add(texttab)

Dim datetab As New DateSignedTab()

datetab.pageNumber = 3

datetab.xPosition = 480

datetab.yPosition = 417

 datetab.recipientId = "1"

datetab.documentId = 1

tabs.dateSignedTabs.Add(datetab)

' create envelope object and assign login info

Dim envelope As New Envelope()

envelope.Login = account

' add one signer to the envelope 

envelope.Recipients = recipients

' send the envelope immediately (otherwise set to "created" to save as draft envelope) 

 envelope.Status = "sent"

' email subject is required 

 envelope.EmailSubject = "Signature Request on Application"

Dim FileName = MyBase.pReferenceNum & AppSettings("PDF_FILE_EXT")

result = envelope.Create(docPDF, FileName)

If result = False Then

 Response.Write("Envelope Creation Failed: " & result & " " & envelope.RestError.message)

Return

End If

 result = envelope.GetRecipientView("afterDocuSign.aspx", True)

If result = False Then

 Response.Write("GetRecipientView Failed: " & result & " " & envelope.RestError.message)

Return

End If

result = envelope.AddTabs(tabs)

If result = False Then

 Response.Write("Tab addition failed: " & result & " " & envelope.RestError.message)

Return

End If

MyBase.pEnvelopeID = envelope.EnvelopeId

MyBase.SetQuoteSession()

 clsQuote.Put_DocuSign_Rec(envelope.EnvelopeId, MyBase.pReferenceNum, envelope.Status)

Response.Redirect(envelope.SenderViewUrl)

Catch ex As Exception

Throw

End Try

End Sub
```

Comment: When loading the recipient view for a known user you just need the email/name (in addition to access to their account via username/password).  When you are loading the recipient view for a captive signer, you must include the clientUserId int eh getRecipientView call.

How are you constructing the GetRecipientView request?

Comment: No matter if I gave clientUserId to a captive singer, I received the same error message "ACCOUNT NOT AUTHORIZED FOR ENVELOPE". I'm using DocuSign.Integration.Client.dll Version 1.4 which downloaded from GitHub. GetRecipientView request is construct in Envelope.cs in DocuSign.Integration.Client project

Comment: Are you testing your demo (ie through your developer sandbox)?  Can you access the envelope when you login through the Console?

Comment: Yes, I was testing my demo through my developer sandbox. I can access the envelope through the Console when I login.

Answer (score 1):

Some possible reasons:

- Checking on an envelope that was created from another account (ie you can only see envelopes in the same account that you've sent, you were a signer, or if you're an admin in the account.
- Wrong environment - i.e. you've created the envelope in production (www) but you are checking on an envelope in your developer sandbox account (demo).
- You are not setting the `clientUserId` property when adding the recipient to the envelope.
- The setting that allows Embedded Signing is not enabled in the account you're sending the envelope from.

For this last one all dev sandbox accounts have Embedding enabled by default but if you're testing in demo and it somehow got turned off in your account you'll have to reach out to your account manager or DS support to have enabled.  Follow up with the nurture emails you received after account creation if you want to talk to an Account Manager.

Comment: The envelop was created with my dev sandbox login and my dev login is also the sender. Even I gave clientUSerID to singer when adding the recipient to the envelope, I still received "This account is not authorized to access the requested envelope" when calling GetRecipientView. My account manager confirmed that my dev sandbox account has Embedding enabled.

Comment: As a test can you please try making the same call through the REST API to see if that works?  You can quickly test through the [API Explorer](http://iodocs.docusign.com/) tool, see Views tab and the last call (Recipient View).  Does that call work for you successfully using the same credentials you're sending through SOAP?

Comment: {
  "statusCode": 404,
  "headers": {
    "cache-control": "private",
    "content-type": "text/html; charset=utf-8",
    "date": "Tue, 07 Jul 2015 18:49:09 GMT",
    "content-length": "2012",
    "vary": "Accept-Encoding",
    "strict-transport-security": "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains"
  }
}

Comment: Finally figured it out. envelope.GetEmbeddedSignerView should be used instead of envelope.GetRecipientView. envelope.GetRecipientView only works when the login email/user name are the same as the signer's. Not sure if this is a bug or by design.